# Information regarding plastic hinges that can hold the position

Tags: mechanical-engineering, plastic

I am trying to find some information regarding the design of plastic hinges that can move freely but also hold a position in any degree, like in this little camera: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/podolabs/podo-the-first-stick-and-shoot-camera

I want to know the considerations of design and if there's any kind of reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what "the considerations of design" means, and readers will have trouble understanding what sort of hinge you're asking about from the problem statement alone. Can you add some details, and a description of the product, to your question so that it relies less on the Kickstarter link for critical information?

Comment: I second @Air's request for a more clear question.  I'd also like to state that I strongly suspect that hinge contains some metal, since it is stated that the casing of said product is silicone rubber.

Comment: Sorry @Air I don't have design considerations right now, I saw the product and was curious to know how it works and how can I use it in the future. In the past I faced the same problem and couldn't give a simple solution like the shown in the kickstarter product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hinge bending with the material rather than mechanically is known as a [living hinge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_hinge). Consideration are placed upon the number times it will be bent during the lifetime and what sort of forces it will experience. However, cannot see how this could this could be kept in place without some additional reinforcement; I am pretty sure there is a sheet piece of metal in there to keep it in shape.

Comment: Thank for your comment @MikeFoxtrot I think that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The type of hinge used in products to hold displays in place at various angles and for similar tasks are called generically **torque hinges**. There are many different constructions. Design would be a typical mechanical engineering problem- coefficients of friction, tolerances and so on.

If they have discrete positions where they prefer to stay they may be called "detent hinges".

Comment: Thanks, useful information. I don't have a broad background in this kind of components.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for you if you can't find an off-the-shelf product that fits your need. There are plastic coolant hoses that can be bent and stay in any position desired to direct the coolant flow for machine tool applications. The hoses are built from articulated plastic ball and socket joints. The hoses have the detent property due to the tight fit(friction) of the ball inside the socket. So just make your own hinge using two of these hose sections as pivot points and attach a plastic plate between the two pivots. It will be a little "bulky" but if you have no size constraints it won't matter. You will have a nice hinge that will stay where you position it, just like the coolant hoses themselves.